# Configuring authorization for Subversion svnserve

Tags: linux, ubuntu, svn

I have setup Subversion 1.6.5 on Ubuntu 9.10 using apt-get and have successfully created a repository with a project simply named 'data' and have added files using svn import. I have added the following to /etc/subversion/config:

```
[general]
anon-access = none
auth-access = write
password-db = passwd
realm = data
```

and have created a file /etc/subversion/passwd which contains:

```
[users]
tim = foo
```

Running `sudo svnserve -d --foreground -r /drobo/repos` on the server, from a client I can checkout the project using `svn checkout svn://tsunami/data`. This all seems to work fine. However when I try to make a commit, I get:

```
svn commit
svn: Commit failed (details follow):
svn: Authorization failed
svn: Your commit message was left in a temporary file:
svn:    '/Users/tim/data/svn-commit.2.tmp'
```

I've tried explicitly using the svn --username and --password options but same problem. Is there anything else I'm missing that would cause the authentication to fail?

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that the conf file in the repository directory should be edited e.g. if you had a repository named /svn/repos then you would edit /svn/repos/conf/svnserve.conf - rather than /etc/subversion/config...

Comment: I think you should say 'repository directory', not 'repository' as the file is not part of the repository itself.

Comment: Edited to clarify exactly what file should be edited :-)